# How to remove spaces at the beginnig of a string but not tabs in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, spaces

I, have to remove leading whitespace from a string except the \t character. 
For example

`"  \thello"`

should become

`"\thello"`

I've tried with

```
stringToTrim = stringToTrim.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

but the regex match also with tab character and the result is

```
"hello"
```

Is it possible to remove leading whitespaces but not tabs with regex?

Comment: Try this `replaceAll("^ +", "");`

Answer (score 7):

In Java, you may use a [*character class subtraction*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) to restrict a more generic pattern.

Use

```
stringToTrim = stringToTrim.replaceFirst("^[\\s&&[^\t]]+", "");
```

Here,

- `^` - matches the start of string
- `[` - start of a character class
- `\\s` - any whitespace pattern
- `&&` - intersection operator
- `[^\t]` - any char but a tab
- `]` - end of the character class
- `+` - a quantifier matching one or more occurrences.

Note since there will only be 1 replacement, it makes sense to use `.replaceFirst` rather than `.replaceAll`.

Comment: Where do you get the explanation all the time?

Comment: @MuratK.: From the head.

Comment: Allright, it always looks like it's copy pasted from somewhere

Comment: @MuratK. When you answer 10+ questions a day trying to fit into the 5 minute window, you will also learn to type fast and using some "pattern" :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only interested in white spaces than `stringToTrim.replaceFirst("^ *", "")` will work for you.